# Xamarin detect control usage on Page with ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, user-input, inotifypropertychanged

I have a content page that holds a listview. each list item consists of a view, viewmodel and model. i can detect the changes on the viewmodel by subsccribing to the property changed event of the properties on the model, that are bound to the view.
But when the value of a property is not the default value (the value on initialization), the property changed event will be called for each of these, when the page is appearing.

But I actually just want to track changes of a user input through the view (e.g. change a text in a textbox).

pseudo code of the scenario:

```
public class CoolViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Model> modelItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> ModelItems
    {
        get { return modelItems; }
        set { SetProperty(ref modelItems, value); }
    }


    public CoolViewModel()
    {
        //To track changes in the model
        foreach (var model in ModelItems)
        {
            model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    //sadly, this is invoked for each property that has a non-default value
    //quickly after this viewmodel is initialized
    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserDidInput = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you wait until after initialization to subscribe to PropertyChanged?

Comment: I have no idea how to know when the "initialization" is finished.

Comment: I assume that was some process you were initiating yourself.  It might be helpful if you posted the actual source of your VM.

Comment: theres really nothing more to it. its a viewmodel for a page with a listview, that has to keep track of when a property on an item in the listview changes, or when the user touches the controls.

Comment: I updated the code, to something that is very close to what I have right now